# Assets\EndTriger.cs(6,1): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i made a starter game from brackeys and i get 3 errors please help me
Script:GameManager

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool gameHasEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;

    public void CompleteLevel ()
    {
        Debug.Log("LEVEL COMPLETE");
    }

    public void EndGame ()
    {
        if (gameHasEnded == false)
        {
            gameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
            Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
        }
        
    }
    void Restart ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

script:EndTriger

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EndTriger : MonoBehaviour

    public GameManager gameManager;
{
    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        gameManager.CompleteLevel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple **TYPO**: In `EndTriger` the vey first `{` should be **before**  `public GameManager gameManager;` ... In general please skip the clutter/noise in your question

Answer (score 0):

EndTriger:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EndTriger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameManager gameManager;
    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        gameManager.CompleteLevel();
    }
}
```